# Add a matplotlib output tab to spyder interface

Tags: python, spyder

I just started using matplotlib and i was wondering if it is possible to add a tab in spyder exclusively dedicated to the plot output.

This is the view I have at the moment and I don't really like the graphs appearing in the console window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmXfx.png

Is there any way this can be done?

p.s.: that only happens when I run the programs from the editor, while running them from the IPython console is showing the results in a new window. If it's not possible to get a dedicated tab, getting the graphs from the editor on a new window would be fine too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) I'm sorry to tell you that at the moment Spyder *doesn't* have a way to do what you're asking for.

Could you post a message in our mailing list about it? If there is enough interest, we could implement a solution for this in a future version :-)